# Win8.1 Universal App - App package generated in Win10 machine not working in Win8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have an Windows 8.1 Universal app developed in a Windows 8.1 machine. The app is compatible with Windows 10 as well. Usually I'd generate app package in VS from Windows 8.1 machine. The package and the app would work just fine in both Win8.1 and Win10.

Recently I have upgraded my machine to Windows 10. Now in Win8.1 machine, the same app is getting crashed when I install it from App package which I generated from the Win10 machine.

Not sure if this behavior is infact an issue. 
Anyone else had this issue before?

Any suggestions on this would greatly help, as I require the app to be compatible with both versions.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any error message? Could you provide the screenshot about error? If you don't have any error message, could you briefly describe the crash? Thank you.